# SQL Convert Milliseconds to Days, Hours, Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I need convert a millisecond value, 85605304.3587 to a value like 0d 18h 21m.
No idea on how to start that, is there something similar to a TimeSpan in SQL like there is in C#?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? The data type in standard SQL (which is what the `sql` tag refers to) would be `interval`

Comment: SQL 2017 is what I am using

Comment: There is no standard named "SQL 2017" but I guess you meant "SQL **Server** 2017"

Comment: The equivalent to `TimeSpan` is `time` but it stores only the *time of day*, not a duration. That means you can't specify times greater than 24 hours. `TimeSpan` can be stored directly into a `time` field

Comment: Where does this value come from? What is its range? Why not store it into a `time` field directly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do the calculation explicitly.  I think it is:

```
select floor(msvalue / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) as days,
       floor(msvalue / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24 as hours,
       floor(msvalue / (1000 * 60)) % 60 as minutes
```

Note:  Some databases use `mod` instead of `%`.

Comment: 1st bracket in 3rd line makes this unrunnable.

Answer (score 2):

In MS SQL SERVER you can use next code:

```
with cte as (
    select cast(85605304.3587 as int) / 1000 / 60 as [min]
), cte2 as (
    select 
        cast([min] % 60 as varchar(max)) as minutes,
        cast(([min] / 60) % 24 as varchar(max)) as hours,
        cast([min] / (60 * 24) as varchar(max)) as days
    from cte
)
select concat(days, 'd ', hours, 'h ', minutes, 'm') as tm
from cte2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using native [date & time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql), maybe:

```
SELECT
    AsDateTime = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 85605304, 0)
  , AsDateTime2 = DATEADD(NANOSECOND, 7 * 100, DATEADD(MICROSECOND, 358, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 85605304, CONVERT(datetime2, CONVERT(datetime, 0)))))
-- Incorrect datetime2 approach I initially did, has some precision loss, probably due to datetime's millisecond issue with 0's, 3's, and 7.'s
--SELECT DontDoThis = DATEADD(NANOSECOND, 7 * 100, DATEADD(MICROSECOND, 358, CONVERT(datetime2, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 85605304, 0))))
```

`datetime` covers only 3 digits beyond seconds, while `datetime2` will maintain 7 digits. Perhaps other ways that give date-like objects exist, I wouldn't know.