# Formulate millis into HHH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, time, vertica

Does anyone know of a way of concatenating millis into an HHH:MM:SS format? Where the hours can go over 24:59:59, but not add another day (as in 1970-01-02 00:00:01). I'd like it to show as 25:00:01 for example.

I can split the time up and concatenate it, but it's a dynamic timeframe, and I wish for the seconds to jump over to minutes etc.

Comment: Do you know how to do **with** days?  If so, drop the day-part of calculations.

Comment: I'm doing it this way, and dropping the date part doesn't solve it unfortunately:("timestampadd"('ms', sum(totaltime::int), '1970-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamptz))::timestamp

Comment: I mean you will need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45146964/2055998) without removing whole days.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in `INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND` data type:

```
daniel=> select '25:59:59'::INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND + 16::INTERVAL SECOND;
 ?column? 
----------
 26:00:15
(1 row)
```